# Multi user network share and resource forks

Tags: macos, nfs

I have a scenario where multiple clients access the same NFS share, where they work with inDesign, Photoshop and such. They have problems with files and dirs going read-only (not in Terminal, though), and I have found the reason to be locks/extended attributes/resource forks. Over samba, it seem to work fine for them all, although they're not happy with the speed we've managed to squeeze out of the samba setup.

How do you manage scenarios like this? What are my options? Would a OS X NFS server not have the clients suffering from the same problem?

Linux 2.6 NFS, tried mounting with "nonamedattr", "noacl" etc. Server forces uid and gid. Clients are OS X 10.6.

**Edit:**

Adobe.com states exactly the same problems (locks, long delays/pausing, intermittent by nature) as we're experiencing.

http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/networks-removable-media-photoshop-cs5.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used NFS for real file shares, but a friend recommended [NFSManager](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5984/nfs-manager) for enabling NFS options on your Mac clients.

You could also try [building netatalk](http://www.lathi.net/pages/afp-rendezvous-on-linux) to enable a native AFP share on the Linux server, which would certainly make your CS users much happier.  Adobe [doesn't officially support](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/networks-removable-media-photoshop-cs5.html) opening and saving files over any network sharing protocols, although my users seem to have no problem when using Bridge to open directly off an OS X Server afp volume.

Comment: I'll consider your answer as correct. It's simply not supported by Adobe. Will give netatalk a shot, but I don't have too high hopes.

Comment: Don't forget to post a follow-up with your experiences, I'd honestly like to know how this one turns out.